# Objective-C iOS pushing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm a bit confused as to what I'm doing wrong. I have a `UIViewController` with a button on one xib and custom `UIViewController` class. I created a second `UIViewController` with a seperate xib (class set to "secondviewcontroller") with seperate custom `UIViewController` class "secondviewcontroller". I want to cause the button on the first `UIViewController` to display my new UIViewController. In the first `UIViewController` I have this code in the event handler for the button push (the class imports "secondviewcontroller.h"):

```
 ...
secondviewcontroller *theVC = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushviewcontroller: theVC animated:YES];
```

and I get an NSexception thrown when it calls `[self.navigationController pushviewcontroller: theVC animated:YES];`

I also tried using the nib name to initialize the second view controller

```
secondviewcontroller *theVC = [[secondviewcontroller alloc] iniwithnibname: @"secondviewcontroller" bundle: nil];
```

and still the same NSException is thrown.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what is the NSException ?

Comment: What exactly does the `NSException` say? (Look into the console there should be more error log).

Comment: Please check all referencing outlets one by one on second controller.
May be there is some extra connecting to object.

Comment: Can you put the NSException here so we can know what actually error you are getting.

Comment: I knew I should have jotted it down last night xD, I'm at work, I'll have to check at lunch and post the exception.